# Clearing Rad Grid data using javascript throwing htmlfile: Invalid argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

Hi i'm working on asp net application. In this i'm trying to clear Rad grid data up on button click using java script. The code which I tried for this is

```
document.getElementById('<%=gvAccount.ClientID %>').outerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('<%=GVAccRefHist.ClientID %>').outerHTML = "";
```

and

```
 document.getElementById('<%=gvAccount.ClientID %>').innerText = null;
    document.getElementById('<%=GVAccRefHist.ClientID %>').innerText = null;
```

But in both cases when I click on the button the data is getting cleared but after that when a Post back occurs then "htmlfile: Invalid" error is being thrown. I want a way to clear Rad grid data using javascript which avoids this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
function RemoveAllRows()
    {
        var masterTable = $find('<%=gvAccount.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView();
        var gridRows = $find('<%=gvAccount.ClientID %>').MasterTableView.get_dataItems();
        var numOfRows = gridRows.length;

        if(numOfRows > 0)
        {

                for (var i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++)
                {
                    masterTable.deleteItem(masterTable.get_dataItems()[index].get_element());
                }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way for it on internet

```
var items = document.getElementById('<%=gvAccount.ClientID %>').getElementsByTagName('td');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            items(i).innerHTML = " ";
```